# what is keycharmap file? why am i getting 'cant open keycharmap file' warning?

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing app using facebook API.

When I push 'login' button from my app,

I am getting 'can't open keychar map file' warnning.

application is running fine but this still bugging me out because

login progress is too slow.

can anybody tell me what is 'keycharmap' file?

why am i getting this warnning?

Comment: don't know exactly,but have your looked in this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740893/android-search-activty-not-starting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible this problem is unrelated to the time your login is taking.  Have you tried logging in through the facebook api in a different environment, like the device browser or a desktop browser?  You could compare the time difference.

Have you checked to see if this error is logged elsewhere?  I found these bug reports: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-2891, http://code.google.com/p/alogcat/issues/detail?id=19, which might be related.  Might be worth checking to see if the error is logged when running other apps, and see if it happens with further logins beyond the first.  Could be outside your app.

Does your login button fire a virtual key event or something? I wonder why the app is trying to access the keycharmap file in the first place.  If you can figure out which line of your button handler code causes the warning to appear, you might be able to track down the cause.