# Android on Long Click is not working properly - custom list

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

my custom listview is not working properly. it works fine till i didnt scroll to the end, but as i scroll to end its onclick feature stop working, i m using custom list extending base adapter..

i have set click listener on to toogle and for it, i have set focusable to false in custom row.

but a thing i noticed is that whenever my list stop taking clicks, following error is generated in logs.

```
05-18 17:54:02.674: W/KeyCharacterMap(4343): Can't open keycharmap file
05-18 17:54:02.674: W/KeyCharacterMap(4343): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/cy8c-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='cy8c-touchscreen'
05-18 17:54:02.674: I/KeyCharacterMap(4343): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

List View

```
 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/main_list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
     android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:divider="@null"
     android:dividerHeight="0dp"
     android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
     android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
 </ListView>
```

Custom Row

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/main_row" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/row_toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/row_fri"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row_fri"
        android:background="@drawable/tog_selector"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Class

```
package com.personoids.personoid;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable;
import android.text.format.Formatter;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener{



    Intent add_alarm;
    ListView main_list;
    StateListDrawable state_list;
    Db_alarm db;
    Alarm_info[] data;
    CategoryAdapter main_adapter;
    TextView next_date;
    TextView next_time;
    TextView next_in;

    int cur_position;
    float text_size;




    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);

        TextView custom_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_title);
        custom_title.setText("Alarm Clock Wise");
        init_vars();
        clock_update();



        populatelist();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if((v.getId() == R.id.add_alarm_text) ||( v.getId() == R.id.add_alarm_icon))
        {
            add_alarm = new Intent(this, Add_Alarm.class);
            add_alarm.putExtra("edit", 0);
            startActivity(add_alarm);






        }

    }









    public void clock_update()
    {
        long  time_millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long hr;
        long min;
        String am_pm = "AM";
        String time = null;
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        int gmt = timeZone.getRawOffset()/(60 * 60 * 1000);
        hr = (time_millis/(1000*60*60)%24)+gmt;
        min = (time_millis/(1000*60)%60);
        if (hr >= 12 && hr <24)
        {

            am_pm = "PM";
        }
        hr= hr%12;
        if(hr == 0)
            hr = 12;
        TextView clock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_clock);
        clock.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d "+ am_pm, hr,min));


        Timer clock_timer = new Timer();

        int delay =(60 - ((int)((time_millis/1000)%60))) * 1000;
        int period = 60000;

        clock_timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
        {
            long hr;
            long min;
            long time_millis;
            String am_pm = "AM";
            String time = null;
            TextView clock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_clock);
            TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
            int gmt = timeZone.getRawOffset()/(60 * 60 * 1000);
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                time_millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                hr = (time_millis/(1000*60*60)%24)+gmt;
                min = (time_millis/(1000*60)%60);
                if (hr >= 12 && hr <24)
                {

                    am_pm = "PM";
                }
                hr= hr%12;
                if(hr == 0)
                    hr = 12;

                clock.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                clock.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d "+ am_pm, hr,min));
                                populatelist();


                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

            }

        }, delay,period);
    }


    public void init_vars()
    {
        RelativeLayout row1= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.row1);
        Drawable row = row1.getBackground();
        next_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.next_alarm_date);
        next_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.next_alarm_time);
        next_in = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.next_alarm_time_left);


        //list_row.getAlpha();

        //row1.setAlpha(80);
        row.setAlpha(80);
        row1.setBackgroundDrawable(row);


        TextView clock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_clock);
        TextView next_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.next_alarm_time);

        Typeface ethnocen = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ethnocen.ttf");
        Typeface goodtime = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/goodtime.ttf");

        TextView add_alarm_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.add_alarm_text);
        ImageView add_alarm_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add_alarm_icon);


        clock.setTypeface(ethnocen);
        next_time.setTypeface(goodtime);

        add_alarm_text.setOnClickListener(this);
        add_alarm_icon.setOnClickListener(this);


        db = new Db_alarm(this);
        data = db.ret_alarm_info();
        main_adapter = new CategoryAdapter(Main.this, data);
        main_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);
        main_list.setAdapter(main_adapter);
        main_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        main_list.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
        registerForContextMenu(main_list);
        text_size = next_time.getTextSize();

        main_list.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                main_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater men_inflater = getMenuInflater();
        men_inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_rows, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.delete:
            db.delete(data[cur_position].getid());
            cancel_pendings(data[cur_position].getid());
            break;
        case R.id.edit:
            add_alarm = new Intent(this, Add_Alarm.class);
            add_alarm.putExtra("alarm_info", data[cur_position]);
            add_alarm.putExtra("links", db.ret_links(data[cur_position].getid()));
            add_alarm.putExtra("edit", 1);
            startActivity(add_alarm);
            break;
        case R.id.duplicate:
            db.duplicate(data[cur_position].getid());
            int id = db.return_last_id();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, launch_alarm.class);
            i.putExtra("id", id);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            data[cur_position] = db.ret_alarm_row(id);
            int secs = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            secs = 60-secs;
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            int day = data[cur_position].days_left()*24;
            int hr = data[cur_position].hours_left()+day;
            hr = hr*60;
            int min = data[cur_position].mins_left()+hr;
            min--;
            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, secs);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
            break;
        case R.id.clear:
            for(int j = 0; j < data.length ; j++)
            {
                db.delete(data[j].getid());
                cancel_pendings(data[j].getid());
            }
            break;
        }
        //Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        populatelist();

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cur_position = pos;

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onResume();
        populatelist();


    }

    private void populatelist() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        data = db.ret_alarm_info();
        main_adapter.update(data);  
        update_next();
    }


    public void update_next()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> min = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int minimum =0;
        int index=0;
        int found =0;
        int counter = 0;
        String[] months = {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
        String[] days = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};


        while(found==0 && counter < data.length)
        {
            if(data[counter].activated()==1)
            {
                minimum=(data[counter].days_left()*24*60)+(data[counter].hours_left()*60)+(data[counter].mins_left());
                min.add(counter);
                found=1;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        Log.i("1", "1");


        if(counter <= data.length)
        {Log.i("2", "1");
        for(int i = counter; i < data.length ; i++)
        {

            if((((data[i].days_left()*24*60)+(data[i].hours_left()*60)+(data[i].mins_left()))<minimum&&
                    data[i].activated()==1))
            {
                minimum=(data[i].days_left()*24*60)+(data[i].hours_left()*60)+(data[i].mins_left());
                min.add(i);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i  < min.size();i++)


            index = min.get(min.size()-1);
        }
        if(data.length == 0 || found==0)
        {
            Log.i("3", "1");
            next_date.setText("");
            next_in.setText("");
            next_time.setText("No Alarm");
            int sizes =(int)((22*getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)+0.5);
            next_time.setTextSize((float)sizes);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("4", "1");
            next_time.setTextSize(text_size);
            Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, data[index].days_left());
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, data[index].hours_left());
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, data[index].mins_left());
            //
            String next_day = days[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1];
            String next_month = months[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)];
            String date = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"";

            if(date.equals("1") || date.equals("21"))
                date = date+"st";

            else if(date.equals("2") || date.equals("22"))
                date = date+"nd";

            else if(date.equals("3") || date.equals("23"))
                date = date+"rd";

            else
                date = date+"th";

            next_date.setText(next_day+" "+date+" "+next_month);
            int time_hrs = data[index].time_hrs();
            String am_pm = "AM";
            if(time_hrs>11)
            {
                if(time_hrs>12)
                    time_hrs = time_hrs % 12;
                am_pm = "PM";
            }
            if(time_hrs == 0)
            {
                time_hrs= 12;
            }
            next_time.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d "+am_pm, time_hrs,data[index].time_mins()));
            next_in.setText(String.format("In %d hrs %d mins", data[index].days_left()*24+data[index].hours_left(), data[index].mins_left()));
        }
    }

    public void cancel_pendings(int id)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, launch_alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        pi.cancel();
    }

    public void set_alarm(int id, int day, int hr, int min)
    {


        Intent i = new Intent(this, launch_alarm.class);
        i.putExtra("id", id);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int secs = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        secs = 60-secs;
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        day = day*24;
        hr = hr+day;
        hr = hr*60;
        min = min+hr;
        min--;
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, secs);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Add Alarm").setIcon(R.drawable.add);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Clear list").setIcon(R.drawable.clear);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Rate").setIcon(R.drawable.rate);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 3, 3, "Upgrade").setIcon(R.drawable.upgrade);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 4, 4, "Help").setIcon(R.drawable.help);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 5, 5, "Close").setIcon(R.drawable.close);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case 0:
            add_alarm = new Intent(this, Add_Alarm.class);
            add_alarm.putExtra("edit", 0);
            startActivity(add_alarm);
            break;
        case 1:
            for(int j = 0; j < data.length ; j++)
            {
                db.delete(data[j].getid());
                cancel_pendings(data[j].getid());
            }
            populatelist();
            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:

            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            finish();
            break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

Custom Adapter

```
package com.personoids.personoid;

import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    private Main catActivity;
    private Alarm_info[] data;
    private Context co;
    RelativeLayout rl ;
    Drawable d;
    Db_alarm db;
    TextView alarm_time;
    TextView remaining;
    TextView sun;
    TextView mon;
    TextView tue;
    TextView wed;
    TextView thu;
    TextView fri;
    TextView sat;
    ToggleButton toggle;


    public CategoryAdapter(Context c, Alarm_info[] datas) {
        co = c;
        data = datas;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        final int pos = position;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) co.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_row, null);
        }

        // v.setOnClickListener(this);
        //v.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.list_row);
        d =rl.getBackground();
        d.setAlpha(80);
        rl.setBackgroundDrawable(d);





        int[] days = data[position].days();

        alarm_time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_alarm_time);
        int time_hrs = data[position].time_hrs();
        String am_pm = "AM";
        if(time_hrs>11)
        {
            if(time_hrs>12)
                time_hrs = time_hrs % 12;
            am_pm = "PM";
        }
        if(time_hrs == 0)
        {
            time_hrs= 12;
        }
        alarm_time.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d "+am_pm, time_hrs,data[position].time_mins()));
        alarm_time.setTag(position);
        remaining = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_rem_time);
        remaining.setTag(position);
        remaining.setText(String.format("%dd %dh %dm", data[position].days_left(),data[position].hours_left(),data[position].mins_left()));
        TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_desc);
        description.setTag(position);
        description.setText(data[position].getdesc());


            sun = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_sun);
            sun.setTag(position);
            if(days[0]==0)
                sun.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#50ffffff"));
            else
                sun.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));


            mon = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_mon);
            mon.setTag(position);
            if(days[1]==0)
                mon.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#50ffffff"));
            else
                mon.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));


            tue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_tue);
            tue.setTag(position);
            if(days[2]==0)
                tue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#50ffffff"));
            else
                tue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));


            wed = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_wed);
            wed.setTag(position);
            if(days[3]==0)
                wed.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#50ffffff"));
            else
                wed.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));


            thu = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_thu);
            thu.setTag(position);
            if(days[4]==0)
                thu.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#50ffffff"));
            else
                thu.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));


            fri = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_fri);
            fri.setTag(position);
            if(days[5]==0)
                fri.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#50ffffff"));
            else
                fri.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));


            sat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_sat);
            sat.setTag(position);
            if(days[6]==0)
                sat.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#50ffffff"));
            else
                sat.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));

        if(data[position].activated()==0)
        {
            remaining.setText("Disabled");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if(data[position].skip==1 && data[position].activated()==1)
        {
            remaining.setText("Snoozed: "+data[position].snooze_duration+" min");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        toggle = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.row_toggle);
        toggle.setTag(position);
        if(data[position].activated()==0)
            toggle.setChecked(false);
        else
            toggle.setChecked(true);
        toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db = new Db_alarm(co);

                if(data[pos].activated==0)
                {

                    db.activate(data[pos].getid());
                    data[pos].activated=1;
                    ((Main) co).set_alarm(data[pos].getid(), data[pos].days_left(), data[pos].hours_left(), data[pos].mins_left());

                }
                else
                {

                    db.deactivate(data[pos].getid());
                    db.iskip(data[pos].getid(), 0);
                    data[pos].activated=0;
                    data[pos].skip=0;
                    ((Main) co).cancel_pendings(data[pos].getid());

                }
                ((Main) co).update_next();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });




        return v;
    }


    public void update(Alarm_info[] datas)
    {
        data=datas;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }




}
```

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: code o.O .. it contains few thousands lines -_- which part u are asking for?
@IftikarUrrhmanKhan

Comment: Please consider about sending your full code with exceptions. We are not augur

Comment: @bmavus i have updated my post :) plz take a look :) thank you :)

Comment: Please Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029782/what-is-keycharmap-file-why-am-i-getting-cant-open-keycharmap-file-warning.