# Android - Can't open keycharmap file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-c2dm, android-logcat

I have C2DM functionality in my app, and occasionally upon receiving a push notification, the activity never appears. When I check logcat, I find this:

```
08-15 12:55:29.213: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Can't open keycharmap file
08-15 12:55:29.213: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Error loading keycharmap file '/data/usr/keychars/mapphone-switch.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.131072.devname='mapphone-switch'
08-15 12:55:29.213: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Can't open keycharmap file
08-15 12:55:29.213: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/mapphone-switch.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.131072.devname='mapphone-switch'
08-15 12:55:29.213: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Can't open keycharmap file
08-15 12:55:29.213: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-15 12:55:31.494: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Can't open keycharmap file
08-15 12:55:31.494: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Error loading keycharmap file '/data/usr/keychars/omap-keypad.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.0.devname='omap-keypad'
08-15 12:57:58.432: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Can't open keycharmap file
08-15 12:57:58.432: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Error loading keycharmap file '/data/usr/keychars/atmxt-i2c.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='atmxt-i2c'
08-15 12:57:58.432: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Can't open keycharmap file
08-15 12:57:58.432: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/atmxt-i2c.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='atmxt-i2c'
08-15 12:57:58.432: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Can't open keycharmap file
08-15 12:57:58.432: W/KeyCharacterMap(10661): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

SO uh.... What's that mean? I googled around, and found this answer: [Android can't open keycharmap file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584733/android-cant-open-keycharmap-file)

But, the only answer to that question has a broken URL in it.

Does anybody know:
1 what this error means, 
2 how to fix it, and 
3 if it is interfering with my push notification activity?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: i dont think it is interfering with your c2dm notification

Comment: I get this error in all of my apps. It doesn't cause any problems, just seems to be a system message. I don't think it will interfere with your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to the Google API in the Android project preferences fixed this issue for me.